# Convert 6 digits date format to standard one in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm working with a dataframe has one messy `date` column with irregular format, ie:

```
          date
0      19.01.01
1      19.02.01
2   1991/01/01
3   1996-01-01
4   1996-06-30
5   1995-12-31
6   1997-01-01
```

Is it possible convert it to standard format `XXXX-XX-XX`, which represents `year-month-date`?  Thank you.

```
          date
0   2019-01-01
1   2019-02-01
2   1991-01-01
3   1996-01-01
4   1996-06-30
5   1995-12-31
6   1997-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` with `yearfirst=True`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ['19.01.01', '19.02.01', '1991/01/01', '1996-01-01', '1996-06-30', '1995-12-31', '1997-01-01']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], yearfirst=True).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         date
0  2019-01-01
1  2019-02-01
2  1991-01-01
3  1996-01-01
4  1996-06-30
5  1995-12-31
6  1997-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends of format, the most general solution is specify each format and use [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y.%m.%d', errors='coerce')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%m/%d', errors='coerce')
date3 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')

df['date'] = date1.combine_first(date2).combine_first(date3)
print (df)

        date
0 2019-01-01
1 2019-02-01
2 1991-01-01
3 1996-01-01
4 1996-06-30
5 1995-12-31
6 1997-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
 df['date'].replace('\/|.','-', regex=True)
```

Comment: Could you please explain this part `('. | /\')`?

Comment: It will find and replace "/" or "." with "-"

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.to_datetime()

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date])
```

Output:

```
0   2001-01-19
1   2001-02-19
2   1991-01-01
3   1996-01-01
4   1996-06-30
5   1995-12-31
6   1997-01-01
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```